# Kubuntu wifi: works good at home but bad on my company wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, network-manager

I'm a newbie here and I'm here to ask some help to solve a wifi issue on my laptop.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 (Kubuntu) and wifi works well on my wifi home (WPA2-PSK): good signal strength and good download/upload speed.

The same laptop wifi configuration has bad numbers when I use it on my company wifi network for which I know only the manufacturer (Cisco). Very bad download/upload speed 5Mbps only.

First I thought it was a company wifi network issue, but if I switch on Windows 10 on the same laptop things change dramatically: I get 100Mps in download/upload and very low latency.

So, I think there's something wrong in my Ubuntu configuration. I've already tried different solution which are collected at [Speed Up Slow WiFi Connection In Ubuntu Linux | It's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/) but none works for me.

Could you help me and give me some advice on how to better investigate this kind of issue?